# html to pdf convert client side javascript with CSS Support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I tried to convert a complete html page to pdf with dynamic values but I can't .

But I saw some API like jspdf but it is not useful for me.
jspdf does not support CSS

is there any library available ?

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS library would be helpful and easy thing to convert the HTML page to PDF or jpg/png format. 
It captures the current dom and converts the rendered content to PDF/png.

Sample Code

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://example.com/', function() {
  page.render('output.pdf');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem here also.
No Basic css support also for MrRio library.
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

But you may refer:

https://github.com/Flamenco/jsPDF

There is css support but there is issues with margin setting for pages.